# Asp.net MVC seems to be binding a List<string> property of my model incorrectly in certain environments

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

We have developed an asp.net mvc application which is an internal application.  Our web app is accessed through other websites/applications on our companies network.  One of the applications is a windows app that displays the site through a web browser in its application.  I've been told by the developers of that application that it uses IE as its browser engine.

My problem is this.  My application takes a payload from the calling systems in the query string.  One of the properties in my model is a list<'string'>, we'll call it listProperty.  So when you want to set listProperty in your call to our site you do this

```
http://mysite.com/?listProperty=value1&listProperty=value2
```

This method works when called through a regular web browser.  It binds to the model as a list containing two strings.  My problem is when it is called through the windows application browser.  When it bind to my model, it binds it as a list containing one string.  The value of the string is a comma separated list of the values.  e.g. value1, value2.

So my questions are:

1. Are there any circumstances where the environment in which an asp.net MVC app is running would cause model bindings to behave differently?
2. Has anyone ever seen behavior like this when binding a list<'string'> property?

Thanks

Comment: If you look at the request made by your windows application with Fiddler does it look the same as the one made by a regular web browser?

Comment: I usually bind to an IEnumerable<string> and it seems to work in all the scenarios I have used it. Not sure I've used your exact scenario though, so it may not help.

Comment: Jesper - Unfortunately, I actually have limited access to the application that is causing this problem, but I may be able to get one of its developers to do it for me.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

what if you tried ? I am not sure it will work, but it's worth a shot

```
http://mysite.com/?listProperty=value1,value2
```